# How to use i18n with makeButton option.text wijimo

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, wijmo, wijmo-grid

current environment 
vue ^2.6.11 
@grapecity/wijmo.cultures: ^5.20221.842 
@grapecity/wijmo.vue2.all: ^5.20213.834

The problem is that I don't know how to add i18n to the `makeButton.text` option

I tried looking through the tutorial and it seemed like it was just a simple string:
[wijmo_grid_cellmaker](https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/api/interfaces/wijmo_grid_cellmaker.ibuttonoptions.html)

I tried `text: "${text? text : this.$t('contractor.table_plan_design_name') }"` it but it doesn't seem to work 
Here is my code:

```
      header: this.$t('contractor.table_plan_design_name'),
      binding: 'plan_design_name',
      minWidth: 135,
      maxWidth: 300,
      allowSorting: false,
      align: 'center',
      cellTemplate: CellMaker.makeButton({
        text: "${text? text : \"プラン選択\" }",
        click: (event, context) => this.onSelectPlanClicking(context),
      }),
      cssClass: 'btn-db',
      cssClassAll: 'single-row',
```

Can you give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!